# How do I secure cross domain calls in PhoneGap, Cordova?

Tags: json, cordova, security, jsonp

I am writing my first secure service that PhoneGap needs to access.

- What data format is the most secure or appropriate to return?

I'm mostly interested in returning JSON, JSON-P, or OData but I can use XML if it's more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Type of the call must be POST 
The server expects JSON data (at least username and password). 
The server sends JSON data back.

The code:

```
function makeCall(){

var URL = "HTTP://remote/server/rest/call";

var jsonData ='{"username":"'+$('#username').val()+'","password":"'+$('#password').val()+'"}';

$.ajax({
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: jsonData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: succesFunction,
        error: errorFunction
    });
}
```

Comment: It appears that these requirements are also needed to secure this service  https://www.info-point-security.com/open_downloads/alt/JavaScript_Hijacking.pdf